# Visual Studio 2012 XAML UI Designer throws exception when adding Pivot and other Microsoft.Phone controls

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, designer, windows-phone-8

Whenever I add any control to my Windows Phone 8 App that is in the Microsoft.Phone namespace (Pivot, Panorama, etc.), the XAML Designer throws:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

The stack traces seem to differ, here is the trace after selecting the Panorama in the Document Outline:

```
at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Design.PanoramaItemAdorner.Activate(ModelItem item)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction.AdornerProvider.InvokeActivate(EditingContext context, ModelItem item)
   at MS.Internal.Features.AdornerProviderFeatureConnector.FeatureProvidersAdded(ModelItem item, IEnumerable`1 extensions)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Policies.PolicyDrivenFeatureConnector`1.OnPolicyItemsChanged(Object sender, PolicyItemsChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Policies.ItemPolicy.OnPolicyItemsChanged(PolicyItemsChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Policies.SelectionPolicy.OnSelectionChanged(Selection newSelection)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.ContextItemManager.SubscribeProxy`1.SubscribeContext(ContextItem item)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.SubscribeContextCallback.Invoke(ContextItem item)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.EditingContext.DefaultContextItemManager.OnItemChanged(ContextItem item)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.EditingContext.DefaultContextItemManager.SetValue(ContextItem value)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.Extensibility.ExtensibilityManager.SetSelection(Selection selection)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.Extensibility.ExtensibilityManager.OnViewModelEarlySceneUpdatePhase(Object sender, SceneUpdatePhaseEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.SceneUpdatePhaseEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, SceneUpdatePhaseEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.ViewModel.SceneViewModel.FireEarlySceneUpdatePhase(SceneUpdatePhaseEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Pipeline.SceneViewUpdateScheduleTask.UpdateEarly()
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Scheduler.ScheduleTask.Update()
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Scheduler.SchedulingService.DispatchTasksAtPriority(DispatcherPriority priority)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Scheduler.SchedulingService.DispatcherToken.Dispatch(Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

If the file is loaded with the controls, the stack trace looks like:

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_InsertValue[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection, UInt32 index, CValue value)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_InsertDependencyObject[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection, UInt32 index, DependencyObject value)
   at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.InsertDependencyObject(Int32 index, DependencyObject value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.InsertInternal(Int32 index, UIElement value
```

The same .xaml file works just fine in Blend, and the designer starts working again as soon as the control is removed.

I've tried uninstalling/repairing the Windows Phone 8 SDK, Visual Studio, and the Silverlight SDKs and Runtimes.

Any other ideas?

Comment: It seems to be related to references to other projects in the solution: I have a Windows Phone 8 project that references a few portable class library projects (which contain the MVVM framework, viewmodels, and models for sharing with a Windows 8 app). If I add the reference to the project directly the error occurs, but if I build the libraries and reference the DLLs it works fine. It's not ideal, but it seems to be working for now.

Comment: Also, sometimes if I delete the references, clean the solution and rebuild, then add the references to the projects one by one it will work, but only until Visual Studio or XDesProc.exe are restarted.

Comment: It's a bit annoying, but this problem started the moment I added a Pivot into the project.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and tried every answer discussed on many forums.

Finally I deleted my 'Solution' file (.sln), not the projects, then added all my project back into my new solution.

Using: VisualStudio Express 2012

Steps:

- In WindowsExplorer delete the Solution (.sln) file that you project is in.
- Open the main project file (.csproj) in VisualStudio.
- Then add all other 'Existing Projects' back into your new solution.

Works great now... hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts maybe related maybe not...

1. Check for any templates which are being used, maybe the designer can't find them and is throwing that error. If the templates are in a shared dictionary try moving them back to the control definition on the page/control as possible.
2. Look at any converter code you are using in the Xaml. Since design time mode doesn't deal with proper data, does your converter(s) handle null situations or bad data situations by returning valid data which a designer could handle? Such as a string.empty verses a raw object to be converted from. In other words does it handle the negative situations properly which design time mode lives in?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues when i add reference System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit and i got this error. After that, i added reference System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit from the path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Client or C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Client and the VS work fine.
Maybe it'll help you.